# How to change a user's password remotely with net user

Tags: powershell

What parameters of `net use` should i set to set a password for a user remotely?

Assuming that inside the script I have to access as admin `mstsc /admin` and change the password of this server by setting the password in question.

I also need to close the session without logging off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# Change user password 
net user username newpassword /domain
# Exit Powershell Session 
Exit-PSSession
```

Comment: And how do I get to a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

To enter the remote computer as admin via powershell:

```
new-pssession -ComputerName MyComputerMachine -credential MyAdminAccount
```

After it will ask you the password for your admin account.

Type the `get-pssession` to find the ID of your created session above. (For example 7)

Now enter the created session by the command bellow:

`enter-pssession 7`

From there on, you will see that your powershell prompt will change the name to remote computer machine like following:

`MyRemoteMachine PS:>`

Which means that you can successfully execute now **net** command:

`net user UserName NewPass /domain`

Than you can execute Exit-Pssession and Remove-Pssession if they are no longer required.

Comment: Thanks.

Is there any way to change the remote server password without accessing it?

Ex: I am accessing server "A" and I want to change the password of server "B" through "net use"

Comment: Well, if your computer is in domain and you want to change User which is in Active Directory there, it's enough to have "/domain" key and you can run it from server A. I'm not sure if it works for non domain stuff.